# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS iOS 9.x

Tags: ios, uiview

I am having a very strange issue in my application. It is crashing when I try to call [self.view layoutIfNeeded] and the exception in Crashlytics is EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS.

self.view is the view of my View Controller.

My view controller outlets are declared as (nonatomic, strong):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewSlider;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

In Crashlytics it is says it is happening only in iOS 9.0 and in 99% in iPhone.

It is really strange and I can't replicate it. Can iOS 9 deallocate randomly deallocate my outlets?

Someone have any issue similar to this?

- EDIT -

Now I am seeing that there are many other issues (all of them giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS) in my app but ONLY in iOS 9.0.2 to 9.2.1.

No one of this issues occurs in iOS < 9.0.2 or iOS >= 9.3.1